# How to assign values from an object list to another list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have couple of lists of these classes.

```
public class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int JobAddressID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
    public int Imagetag { get; set; }
}

public class ImageView
{
    public int tag { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What i would like is assign the values from one list to another without horrible looking foreach loops, something using linq maybe?

My lists are (they are instantiated and ready to go)

```
 List<Image> _imageList 
 List<ImageView> ImageView
```

Pseudocode

```
ImageView.tag = Image.ImageID
 ImageView.ImageData = ImageBytes
```

I have tried this but still i need another loop to assign the values from blah to my Imageview.

```
var blah = _imageList.GroupBy(i => new { i.ImageID, i.ImageBytes }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Use Automapper for this task, makes it really easy to map object values to different objects

Comment: _without foreach loops_  Why you do not want to use loops? Linq will use them under the hood

Comment: ok so `_imageList` is of type `List<Image>` then you group by `ImageID` and `ImageBytes` then what shall happen afterwards? do you want an array of `ImageView [ ]` as result? sorry but I don't get it yet

Comment: "to assign the values from blah to my Imageview." `blah` will have multiple key values, how do you intend it to map it to a single `Imageview` ? or is it a typo and you meant to say it in plural?

Comment: Sorry but that is not possible. Either you write a loop and do that, or you use existing solutions, which in turn, will internally do loops for you.

Comment: please define what you expect as result? a `List<ImageView>` ? with the `tag` and `ImageData` having the same values as your groups? if so, then a simple select statement after the grouping would suffice

Comment: you can do a simple LINQ Select, but if you have more than 2 common properties, AutoMapper is a way to go

Comment: can you please describe what you expect from grouping by a `byte [ ]` ?  the problem here is that it will be  a comparison of reference not a comparison of array content!

Comment: What do you mean by *"they are instantiated and ready to go"*, does `ImageView` contain anything at all? or it's an empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would need a `Select` after the grouping in which you create a new `ImageView`:

```
var blah = _imageList.GroupBy(i => new { i.ImageID, i.ImageBytes })
                     .Select(x => new ImageView
                     {
                        tag = x.Key.ImageID,
                        ImageData = x.Key.ImageBytes
                     }).ToList();
```

disclaimer: I did not take the other 2 properties into account, since you did not specify them in your question.

Attention the grouping by a `byte [ ]` can lead to unexpected results. Be aware that a comparison will be between the references of the array and not between the content of them. So you will have only the same group if the different object really share the **same reference** of a single `byte [ ] ImageBytes`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Looks much tidy than a foreach loop. Cheers.